# Voronoi Texture in Blender

Tags: texturing, procedural

Trying to achieve this simple Voronoi texture (below) but i'm having trouble figuring out what to plug where; i'm kind a missing a ... combine node?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the warping in the size of the pattern, you can use a Noise Texture as an input for the scale. I mixed it with white using a MixRGB node for better control over the strength

[image: Pattern]

Comment: Three completely different answers that make evident how unclear the question is!

Answer (score 2):

### Use Color output

You are probably using a different setup from what is depicted in the first image.

My wild guess is that you are using the **Distance** output of the Voronoi texture node instead of the **Color**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, what you are looking for can be done using distance to edge.

[image]

[image]